# How to set Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage HttpVersion?

Tags: c#, .net, http, uwp

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage has the Version attribute which I believe to be the HTTP version of the request, but I can't find where this same attributes is in Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage. If this isn't the right attributes to set the HttpRequest version, which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it this way:

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter(); 
filter.MaxVersion = HttpVersion.Http11;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(filter);
```

[HttpBaseProtocolFilter.MaxVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.maxversion)